# Javascript drop event

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have some code which allows me to drop an html `<div>` into certain 'spaces'  and once a space is occupied the code doesn't allow another `<div>` to be moved in until the space has been emptied.  It is set out below and works perfectly.

```
function drop(ev, p) {
    if (ev.target.hasChildNodes() == false) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        //more code
```

It is called by:

```
<div id="myID" ondrop="drop(event, myP)">
```

There are cases when I want to pre-populate my spaces.  Since I don't have an event I've written a second function as below:

```
function drop_setup (playerDiv, p, player) {
    var data = player.toString();    
    document.getElementById(playerDiv).appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    //more code follows
```

I'm calling this from my page load using:

```
drop_setup('QBdiv',myP, myDiv);
```

The screen looks like a space has been filled but I can drop another `<div>` over it so this isn't working.  Any help most welcome.

Comment: It looks player.toString() returns empty string. If there should be some data I'm player, check the problem I'm the part or your code which assigns data to player.

Comment: I've checked that and data gets the same results in both functions.  I have realised that the second function is adding the node but appears to be adding it below as if there is already a child (this doesn't happen in the first example) and I've tried inserting before but that just moves the logo down

Comment: @HenryM can you create a failing bin or fiddle?